# Are exchange compliance plan submissions publicly available and where they can be found?

Tags: stocks, nasdaq

I've encountered several times that a company doesn't meet certain listing standards for an exchange (e.g. min stockholder equity or market capitalization on NASDAQ), submits a compliance plan to the exchange and then gets a grace period to regain compliance with those listing requirements. 
Question:
Are those compliance plans available publicly? Where can they be found (in particular for NASDAQ)?

Comment: Related question was asked [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/83298/how-does-a-company-responds-to-a-non-compliance-letter-from-nyse)